# Query posts from newest category

Tags: posts, categories, query

Is it possible to query posts from latest category only? I know that categories dont store date but I know also that newer categories have bigger IDs

My standard query:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php if (!empty($paged)) {
            $paged = $paged;
        } elseif (get_query_var('paged')) {
            $paged = get_query_var('paged');
        } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
            $paged = get_query_var('page');
        } else {
            $paged = 1;
        }
        $argsmi = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 6, 'order' => 'DESC', 'paged' => $paged);
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($argsmi);
        if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
                <!-- do stuff -->
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php if (function_exists('wp_paginate')) {
                wp_paginate();
            } ?>
            <?php $wp_query = null;
            $wp_query = $temp;
            wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?> 


    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: To make it more solid, you could actually do it with 'term post date', rather than by the ID, using `term meta`. Using `term meta`, give the taxonomy terms meta for 'creation date' and set the default value to now. Then you could write your WP_Query accordingly. [link]https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/how-to-use-term-meta-data-in-wordpress/

Comment: ... Doing it by ID isn't solid as may delete terms, leaving the one with highest ID in the database not be the newest one.

Comment: @Dan. in what case would deleting terms result in the remaining term with highest ID not then being the newest? IDs don't get reused, they only increment.

Comment: is the real question about how to find the category with the highest ID?

Comment: @Michael you're right sorry wasn't thinking straight

Comment: Still, OP may benefit from being able to set the date, or some other term_meta, if he ever wants to change the order